# R coxme: How to get study-specific treatment effect and 95% confidence interval from a mixed effect model?

Tags: r, mixed-models, cox

I am using the `coxme` to fix a mixed effect Cox model. I have two random effects in the model (intercept [baseline hazard] and slope of the treatment). After running the model, I got the fixed coefficients and random effects output:

```
Fixed coefficients
                                 coef exp(coef)   se(coef)     z    p
treatment                 0.420463710 1.5226675 0.28313885  1.49 0.14

Random effects
     Group  Variable          Std Dev    Variance   Corr      
     Study  Intercept         1.3979618  1.9542971 -0.6995296
            treatment         0.4815433  0.2318839
```

I also used the `ranef` to get the random effect coefficients for each study. Outpout:

```
         Intercept    treatment
Study1   -1.591497    0.5479255
Study2    1.276003   -0.4392570
Study3   -1.051512    0.3621938
Study4    1.367005   -0.4708623
```

I was wondering how I can obtain the treatment effect (coefficient) and 95% CI for each study separately. Can I get the point estimate by summing up the overall coefficient of fixed effect and study-specific random effect (e.g. `0.420463710` + `0.5479255` for Study1)? But what about the 95%CI?

Is there any way to get the study-specific treatment effect and 95% CI (and the study's weight), like in `ipdforest` in Stata?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'll say for the record (*much* belatedly) that there's not an obvious way to get conditional standard deviations of the random effects from `lme`: the mathematics in `vignette("lmer", package = "lme4")` applies, but one would have to figure out how to extract the quantities `V` and `Lambda_{theta}` from an `lme` object ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a not-completely-worked out answer, with some caveats and commentary:

The general recipe is that if you have a set of linear combinations of parameters (fixed and random) you want to apply — combine that into a matrix `M` — along with a set of parameters (fixed and random) `B` and a covariance matrix (for the same parameters) `S`, then the predictions are `M %*% B` and the variances of the predictions are `diag(M %*% S %*% t(S))` (there are slightly more efficient ways to compute this ...)

The `coxme.condsd` function below generates what I would call *conditional standard deviations* for a given set of predictor variables. This isn't quite the same as generating the conditional standard deviations of the *slopes*; that would involve a different set of linear combinations. But it's at least the beginning of an answer (this is also posted [here](https://gist.github.com/bbolker/bbfaf27accc6c9c72a5e2d572bd0de94), and will hopefully be incorporated into `coxme` at some point in the future ...)

```r
coxme.condsd <- function(fit,
                         data = eval(getCall(fit)$data),
                         grpvar,
                         rform,
                         sd.only = TRUE) {
    ## model.frame() to get a sanitized (NA-free) data set
    vf <- all.vars(fit$formula$fixed)
    ## pick apart random effects terms
    vr <- (fit$formula$random
        |> lapply(function(x) lapply(lme4::findbars(x), all.vars))
        |> unlist(recursive = TRUE)
    )
    mf <- model.frame(reformulate(c(vf, vr)), data)
    ## indicator matrix for grouping variable
    Fmat <- t(Matrix::fac2sparse(mf[[grpvar]]))
    ## Z matrix
    Xr <- model.matrix(rform, mf)
    ## was (special case): Z <- cbind(Fmat, Fmat*mf$ph.ecog)
    Z <- t(Matrix::KhatriRao(t(Xr), t(Fmat)))
    ## remove intercept from RHS of fixed formula
    fform <- update(fit$formula$fixed[-2], ~ 0 + .)
    X <- model.matrix(fform, data = mf)
    ## respect order of vars in cov matrix: RE folowed by FE coefs
    ZX <- cbind(Z,X)
    V <- as.matrix(fit$variance)
    V2 <- ZX %*% V %*% t(ZX)
    if (sd.only) sqrt(diag(V2)) else V2
}

## cc <- c(ranef(fit)$inst[,1], ranef(fit)$inst[,2], coef(fit))
## head(drop(ZX %*% cc))
## head(fit$linear.predictor)
fit <- coxme(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + age + (1 + ph.ecog|inst), lung)

## this gets conditional SD (including both fixed & random effect uncertainty,
##  but using a plug-in estimate of the RE *variances*) for each observation in
## the original data set
coxme.condsd(fit, grpvar = "inst", rform = ~1 + ph.ecog)
```