# Predicting survival and 95% confidence interval from a mixed effects Cox model (coxme)

Tags: r, predict, mixed-models, cox-regression

I fitted a mixed effects cox model using the package coxme. The model includes a two-level variable as fixed effect and a random intercept.

I want to predict survival probability and 95% confidence interval over time for each level of the categorical variable based on the fixed effects only (similar to re.form=NA in predict.merMod).

Constructing predictions is straightforward when there is no random effect using predict.coxph in the survival package, but predict.coxme does not provide standard deviations and new datasets are not yet supported.

**How can I compute predicted survivor curve and 95%CI based on the coxme model (with a new dataset and fixed effects only)?**

Sample code using lung dataset in the survival package:

```
library(survival)
library(coxme)

# format data
df <- na.omit(lung[, c("inst", "time", "status","sex")])
df$sex <- factor(df$sex)

# fit model
cme <- coxme(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + (1|inst), data = df)
summary(cme)

# build dummy dataset
pred_data = data.frame(sex=unique(lung$sex))

# get predicted values and se (does not work)
pred <- predict(cme, newdata, type= "lp", se.fit =T)
```

**Related questions and answers**

The code here seems close to what is needed, but I was not able to adapt it to get predicted values and 95%CI for a new dataset and using only fixed effects: [R coxme: How to get study-specific treatment effect and 95% confidence interval from a mixed effect model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58227785/r-coxme-how-to-get-study-specific-treatment-effect-and-95-confidence-interval)

This question is also similar: [Plotting adjusted survival curve for a mixed-effects cox regression and/or time interaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77654561/plotting-adjusted-survival-curve-for-a-mixed-effects-cox-regression-and-or-time) but there are convergence issues when I fit my original data set with a frailty coxph model and I would like to know if there is a way to get predicted survival probability and confidence bands for a coxme model.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `ehahelper::predict_coxme`.

```
> # remotes::install_github('junkka/ehahelper')  ## install package
> ehahelper::predict_coxme(cme, pred_data, se.fit=TRUE)
$fit
         1          2 
-0.3191101 -0.8478545 

$se.fit
[1] 0.1010445 0.2684685
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. Using these predicted estimates and se, how could one then compute the survival probability over time?

Comment: @frederic.ddb I'm not sure, you probably need different `pred_data` which currently has just two rows. Since you're mentioning time, it probably should be included in a way. Essentially `predict`, as the name may suggest, applies the model on new data that may extent to the future.